# Android use findViewById in PreferenceFragment gives NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-preferences

I have a preference screen that contains a custom layout :

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Preference
    android:key="myKey"
    android:layout="@layout/my_layout" />


<ListPreference
    app:defaultValue="@string/defaultGender"
    app:entries="@array/gender_entries"
    app:entryValues="@array/gender_values"
    app:key="gender"
    app:title="@string/gender"
    app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
```

I am trying to set the value of a TextView inside `my_layout` :

```
public static class MyFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_screen, rootKey);
        TextView textView= (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        textView.setText("XXX");
    }

}
```

But I get `NullPointerException` on the `textView.setText("XXX");`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try set you text in the onViewCreated function.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    TextView textView= (TextView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    textView.setText("XXX");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to extend Preference with your own class, and then override the  onBindViewHolder(...) method.  Something like this:

```
public class AppDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {
...
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PreferenceViewHolder viewHolder) {
    super.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder);
    View helpView = viewHolder.findViewById(R.id.help_button);
    ...
```